# Reading dictionary stored on text file and convert to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a text file that contains a series of data in the form of dictionary.
I would like to read and store as a data frame in pandas.
How would I read.
I read pd.csv yet it does  not give me the dataframe.
Can anyone help me with that?
You can download the text file [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DbfQxBJKHvWO2YlKZCmeIN4al3xG8Wq5)

Thanks,

Zep,

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Looking at the file, this seems like a standard json file. However all the data inside is nested which won't work with a pandas dataframe so you'll need to change the shape of the de-serialized json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have a nested json. Try using json_normalize instead:

```
import requests     #<-- requests library helps us handle http-requests
import pandas as pd

id_ = '1DbfQxBJKHvWO2YlKZCmeIN4al3xG8Wq5'
url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id={}&export=download'.format(id_)
r = requests.get(url)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(r.json())
print(df.columns)
```

---

**or** from hard drive, and json_normalize as wants to read a dictionary object and not a path:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('myfile.json') as f:
    jsonstr = json.load(f)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(jsonstr)
```

Returns:

```
Index(['average.accelerations', 'average.aerialDuels', 'average.assists',
       'average.attackingActions', 'average.backPasses', 'average.ballLosses',
       'average.ballRecoveries', 'average.corners', 'average.crosses',
       'average.dangerousOpponentHalfRecoveries',
       ...
       'total.successfulLongPasses', 'total.successfulPasses',
       'total.successfulPassesToFinalThird', 'total.successfulPenalties',
       'total.successfulSmartPasses', 'total.successfulThroughPasses',
       'total.successfulVerticalPasses', 'total.throughPasses',
       'total.verticalPasses', 'total.yellowCards'],
      dtype='object', length=171)
```

---

Another idea would be to store the nested objects in a Series (and you can let a dictionary hold that those series).

```
dfs = {k: pd.Series(v) for k,v in r.json().items()}    
print(dfs.keys()) 
# ['average', 'seasonId', 'competitionId', 'positions', 'total', 'playerId', 'percent'])
print(dfs['percent'])
```

Returns:

```
aerialDuelsWon                   23.080
defensiveDuelsWon                18.420
directFreeKicksOnTarget           0.000
duelsWon                         33.470
fieldAerialDuelsWon              23.080
goalConversion                   22.581
headShotsOnTarget                 0.000
offensiveDuelsWon                37.250
penaltiesConversion               0.000
shotsOnTarget                    41.940
...
yellowCardsPerFoul               12.500
dtype: float64
```

The data only has one entry though.

Comment: Dear Anton,
Thanks for the multiple solutions.
Related to your first solution, If I want to read from the local drive, I used pd.read_csv and destination of the file. It did not work.
Can you advice how used your first solution using the file in local drive.
Thanks

Comment: @Zephyr sorry went for lunch. updated.

Comment: Thanks Anton, I appreciate much. Yes, the data file only contains 1 row. However, I am json file that contains nested dictionaries. I tried the same method, But dataframe showed differently. If you dont mind, May  I discuss with you on that too?

Comment: @Zephyr Feel free to contact me.

Comment: Can you briefly advise me how to flatten nested json.

Comment: Unfortunately, Pc is ongoing window update. 

Comment: @Zephyr wait now. The whole flattening is handled by json_normalize here. What is your real question?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I posted a new question as follow in the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/52795561/9561497

Answer (score 1):

You can convert you data to json after reading it as string, then use `pandas.read_json()` to convert your json to a dataframe.

Example:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

f = open("file.txt", "w+")
contents = f.read()
contents = contents.replace("\n", "")
json_data = json.loads(contents)
df = json_normalize(json.loads(data))
```

You should have your data as a dataframe after that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi I just tried out and it showed the following error:
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Thats because of your new line character. you need to strip that out, check the updated answer above.

Comment: Your data also needs to be normalized. This will require you to use normalize_json

Comment: Thanks Devdob. Appreciate your advice.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I have other json file that contain nested elements. How can I flatten the nested json data? Can you briefly explain. I used the following code:

Position_data = json_normalize(data =jsonstr['events'], record_path='positions', meta = ['x','y','x','y'] )

positions has nested data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181815/discussion-between-zephyr-and-devdob).