# Flattening Nested JSON File to Pandas DF

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am starting with APIs and JSON data structure, and I am having a hard time to properly flat a file of this structure.

```
import json


print(json.dumps(json_data["orders"][5], sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Results in:

```
{
    "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Order/1805223231558",
    "app_id": 580111,
    "billing_address": {
        "address1": "fsalj",
        "address2": "lajsd",
        "city": "aklsdas",
        "company": null,
        "country": "Denmark",
        "country_code": "DK",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "fo",
        "latitude": null,
        "longitude": null,
        "name": "fo",
        "phone": null,
        "province": null,
        "province_code": null,
        "zip": "1234"
    },
    "browser_ip": "152.115.81.234",
    "buyer_accepts_marketing": false,
    "cancel_reason": null,
    "cancelled_at": null,
    "cart_token": "919658f9255451c77cb3f1736f54150e",
    "checkout_id": 11639577313350,
    "checkout_token": "712110938f2bb22e2fcfcc5352668296",
    "client_details": {
        "accept_language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "browser_height": 766,
        "browser_ip": "152.115.81.234",
        "browser_width": 1440,
        "session_hash": "345c24262f7a38e8467d28c4686c3ffb",
        "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"
    },
    "closed_at": null,
    "confirmed": true,
    "contact_email": "jhf+lko@organicbasics.com",
    "created_at": "2019-10-18T14:27:47+02:00",
    "currency": "DKK",
    "customer": {
        "accepts_marketing": false,
        "accepts_marketing_updated_at": "2019-10-18T13:51:46+02:00",
        "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Customer/2579389612102",
        "created_at": "2019-10-18T13:51:46+02:00",
        "currency": "DKK",
        "default_address": {
            "address1": "fsalj",
            "address2": "lajsd",
            "city": "aklsdas",
            "company": null,
            "country": "Denmark",
            "country_code": "DK",
            "country_name": "Denmark",
            "customer_id": 2579389612102,
            "default": true,
            "first_name": "",
            "id": 2742281863238,
            "last_name": "fo",
            "name": "fo",
            "phone": null,
            "province": null,
            "province_code": null,
            "zip": "1234"
        },
        "email": "jhf+lko@organicbasics.com",
        "first_name": "",
        "id": 2579389612102,
        "last_name": "fo",
        "last_order_id": 1805223231558,
        "last_order_name": "OBTART1013",
        "marketing_opt_in_level": null,
        "multipass_identifier": null,
        "note": null,
        "orders_count": 1,
        "phone": null,
        "state": "disabled",
        "tags": "",
        "tax_exempt": false,
        "tax_exemptions": [],
        "total_spent": "309.00",
        "updated_at": "2019-10-18T14:27:47+02:00",
        "verified_email": true
    },
    "customer_locale": "en",
    "device_id": null,
    "discount_applications": [],
    "discount_codes": [],
    "email": "jhf+lko@organicbasics.com",
    "financial_status": "paid",
    "fulfillment_status": null,
    "fulfillments": [],
    "gateway": "gift_card",
    "id": 1805223231558,
    "landing_site": "/password",
    "landing_site_ref": null,
    "line_items": [
        {
            "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/LineItem/4020212432966",
            "destination_location": {
                "address1": "fsalj",
                "address2": "lajsd",
                "city": "aklsdas",
                "country_code": "DK",
                "id": 1600208109638,
                "name": "fo",
                "province_code": "",
                "zip": "1234"
            },
            "discount_allocations": [],
            "fulfillable_quantity": 1,
            "fulfillment_service": "manual",
            "fulfillment_status": null,
            "gift_card": false,
            "grams": 0,
            "id": 4020212432966,
            "name": "Boxers 2-pack - Navy / S",
            "origin_location": {
                "address1": "Baldersgade 45",
                "address2": "st th",
                "city": "Copenhagen",
                "country_code": "DK",
                "id": 1027147235428,
                "name": "Tarteletter",
                "province_code": "",
                "zip": "2200"
            },
            "pre_tax_price": "239.20",
            "pre_tax_price_set": {
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "239.20",
                    "currency_code": "DKK"
                },
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "239.20",
                    "currency_code": "DKK"
                }
            },
            "price": "299.00",
            "price_set": {
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "299.00",
                    "currency_code": "DKK"
                },
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "299.00",
                    "currency_code": "DKK"
                }
            },
            "product_exists": true,
            "product_id": 2631134511204,
            "properties": [],
            "quantity": 1,
            "requires_shipping": true,
            "sku": "M-BXR-C-NA-S",
            "tax_lines": [
                {
                    "price": "59.80",
                    "price_set": {
                        "presentment_money": {
                            "amount": "59.80",
                            "currency_code": "DKK"
                        },
                        "shop_money": {
                            "amount": "59.80",
                            "currency_code": "DKK"
                        }
                    },
                    "rate": 0.25,
                    "title": "Moms"
                }
            ],
            "taxable": true,
            "title": "Boxers 2-pack",
            "total_discount": "0.00",
            "total_discount_set": {
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "0.00",
                    "currency_code": "DKK"
                },
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "0.00",
                    "currency_code": "DKK"
                }
            },
            "variant_id": 23536501817444,
            "variant_inventory_management": "shopify",
            "variant_title": "Navy / S",
            "vendor": "ORGANIC COTTON"
        }
    ],
    "location_id": null,
    "name": "OBTART1013",
    "note": null,
    "note_attributes": [],
    "number": 13,
    "order_number": 1013,
    "order_status_url": "https://tarteletter.organicbasics.com/1396572260/orders/bc731580366deaa9f5fded639f81caa5/authenticate?key=8be7f8a50658d61c1b1a04c643c63bfb",
    "payment_gateway_names": [
        "gift_card"
    ],
    "phone": null,
    "presentment_currency": "DKK",
    "processed_at": "2019-10-18T14:27:46+02:00",
    "processing_method": "gift_cards_only",
    "reference": null,
    "referring_site": "",
    "refunds": [],
    "shipping_address": {
        "address1": "fsalj",
        "address2": "lajsd",
        "city": "aklsdas",
        "company": null,
        "country": "Denmark",
        "country_code": "DK",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "fo",
        "latitude": null,
        "longitude": null,
        "name": "fo",
        "phone": null,
        "province": null,
        "province_code": null,
        "zip": "1234"
    },
    "shipping_lines": [
        {
            "carrier_identifier": null,
            "code": "Standard Shipping",
            "delivery_category": null,
            "discount_allocations": [],
            "discounted_price": "10.00",
            "discounted_price_set": {
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "10.00",
                    "currency_code": "DKK"
                },
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "10.00",
                    "currency_code": "DKK"
                }
            },
            "id": 1488804872262,
            "phone": null,
            "price": "10.00",
            "price_set": {
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "10.00",
                    "currency_code": "DKK"
                },
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "10.00",
                    "currency_code": "DKK"
                }
            },
            "requested_fulfillment_service_id": null,
            "source": "shopify",
            "tax_lines": [],
            "title": "Standard Shipping"
        }
    ],
    "source_identifier": null,
    "source_name": "web",
    "source_url": null,
    "subtotal_price": "299.00",
    "subtotal_price_set": {
        "presentment_money": {
            "amount": "299.00",
            "currency_code": "DKK"
        },
        "shop_money": {
            "amount": "299.00",
            "currency_code": "DKK"
        }
    },
    "tags": "",
    "tax_lines": [
        {
            "price": "59.80",
            "price_set": {
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "59.80",
                    "currency_code": "DKK"
                },
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "59.80",
                    "currency_code": "DKK"
                }
            },
            "rate": 0.25,
            "title": "Moms"
        }
    ],
    "taxes_included": true,
    "test": false,
    "token": "bc731580366deaa9f5fded639f81caa5",
    "total_discounts": "0.00",
    "total_discounts_set": {
        "presentment_money": {
            "amount": "0.00",
            "currency_code": "DKK"
        },
        "shop_money": {
            "amount": "0.00",
            "currency_code": "DKK"
        }
    },
    "total_line_items_price": "299.00",
    "total_line_items_price_set": {
        "presentment_money": {
            "amount": "299.00",
            "currency_code": "DKK"
        },
        "shop_money": {
            "amount": "299.00",
            "currency_code": "DKK"
        }
    },
    "total_price": "309.00",
    "total_price_set": {
        "presentment_money": {
            "amount": "309.00",
            "currency_code": "DKK"
        },
        "shop_money": {
            "amount": "309.00",
            "currency_code": "DKK"
        }
    },
    "total_price_usd": "46.01",
    "total_shipping_price_set": {
        "presentment_money": {
            "amount": "10.00",
            "currency_code": "DKK"
        },
        "shop_money": {
            "amount": "10.00",
            "currency_code": "DKK"
        }
    },
    "total_tax": "59.80",
    "total_tax_set": {
        "presentment_money": {
            "amount": "59.80",
            "currency_code": "DKK"
        },
        "shop_money": {
            "amount": "59.80",
            "currency_code": "DKK"
        }
    },
    "total_tip_received": "0.0",
    "total_weight": 0,
    "updated_at": "2019-10-18T14:27:50+02:00",
    "user_id": null
}
```

I am aware of the function json_normalize but the problem is that when it gets to "line_items", json_normalize is not able to handle and places everything under the same column and row in the DF.
From what I understand, "Line_item" is another dictionary/object, my end goal is to flat this json, creating a column for all key:value outside "line_items", and creating a new row for each item inside "line_items"; and the information outside "line_items" gets repeated.

I have also tried the one below, defining the "path". But I run into this error: SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

```
df2 = json_normalize(json_data['orders'], sep = "_",  
                     record_path = "line_items",
                     meta = 
                     "fulfillable_quantity",
                     "fulfillment_service",
                     "fulfillment_status",
                     "grams",
                     "id",
                     "price",
                     "product_id",
                     "quantity",
                     "requires_shipping",
                     "sku",
                     "title",
                     "variant_id",
                     "variant_title",
                     "vendor",
                     "name",
                     "gift_card",
                     "properties",
                     "taxable",
                     "tax_lines",
                     "total_discount",
                     "total_discount_set",
                     "discount_allocations",
                     meta_prefix = "line_")
```

Any suggestions on how to make this transformation?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795561/flattening-nested-json-in-pandas-data-frame

Comment: The `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument` is happening because the values you passs to the `meta` argument are not enclosed in brackets, so it's treating the second value (`fulfillment_service`) as a new argument

Comment: Hey @IanThompson, thanks for the reference, but I have also looked into recursion solutions, but I doesn't solve things completely. I can't have my file flattened completely because the number of "items" inside the "line_items" object varies from transaction to transaction. I need to figure out how to "flat" until the first item, and then created rows based on the number of items of one transaction. 
Does it makes sense?