# Convert JSON file to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I would like to convert a JSON to Pandas dataframe.

My JSON looks like:
like:

```
{ 
   "country1":{ 
      "AdUnit1":{ 
         "floor_price1":{ 
            "feature1":1111,
            "feature2":1112
         },
         "floor_price2":{ 
            "feature1":1121
         }
      },
      "AdUnit2":{ 
         "floor_price1":{ 
            "feature1":1211
         },
         "floor_price2":{ 
            "feature1":1221
         }
      }
   },
   "country2":{ 
      "AdUnit1":{ 
         "floor_price1":{ 
            "feature1":2111,
            "feature2":2112
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I read the file from GCP using this code:

```
project = Context.default().project_id
sample_bucket_name = 'my_bucket'
sample_bucket_path = 'gs://' + sample_bucket_name
print('Object: ' + sample_bucket_path + '/json_output.json')

sample_bucket = storage.Bucket(sample_bucket_name)
sample_bucket.create()
sample_bucket.exists()

sample_object = sample_bucket.object('json_output.json')
list(sample_bucket.objects())
json = sample_object.read_stream()
```

My goal to get Pandas dataframe which looks like:

[image: Given dataframe]

I tried using [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html), but didn't succeed.

Comment: How about [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)?

Comment: I tried it, but the result isn't good:
https://c2n.me/44pYvfb

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795561/flattening-nested-json-in-pandas-data-frame) answer, as I think you need to "flatten" the json first for you to use `pd.read_json(json.dumps(json_dictionary))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```py
def flatten_dict(d):
    """ Returns list of lists from given dictionary """
    l = []
    for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            flatten_v = flatten_dict(v)
            for my_l in reversed(flatten_v):
                my_l.insert(0, k)

            l.extend(flatten_v)

        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for l_val in v:
                l.append([k, l_val])

        else:
            l.append([k, v])

    return l
```

This function receives a dictionary (including nesting where values could also be lists) and flattens it to a list of lists.

Then, you can simply:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(flatten_dict(my_dict))
```

Where `my_dict` is your JSON object.
Taking your example, what you get when you run `print(df)` is:

```py
          0        1             2         3     4
0  country1  AdUnit1  floor_price1  feature1  1111
1  country1  AdUnit1  floor_price1  feature2  1112
2  country1  AdUnit1  floor_price2  feature1  1121
3  country1  AdUnit2  floor_price1  feature1  1211
4  country1  AdUnit2  floor_price2  feature1  1221
5  country2  AdUnit1  floor_price1  feature1  2111
6  country2  AdUnit1  floor_price1  feature2  2112
```

And when you create the dataframe, you can name your columns and index

Answer (score 5):

Nested JSONs are always quite tricky to handle correctly.

A few months ago, I figured out a way to provide an "universal answer" using the beautifully written ***flatten_json_iterative_solution*** from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-flatten-deeply-nested-json-objects-in-non-recursive-elegant-python-55f96533103d): which unpacks iteratively each level of a given json.

Then one can simply transform it to a *Pandas.Series* then *Pandas.DataFrame* like so:

```
df = pd.Series(flatten_json_iterative_solution(dict(json_))).to_frame().reset_index()
```

[Intermediate Dataframe result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFdqN.png)

Some data transformation can easily be performed to split the index in the columns names you asked for:

```
df[["index", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]] = df['index'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split('_')))
```

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dlVE.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
 from google.cloud import storage
 import pandas as pd

 storage_client = storage.Client()
 bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('test-mvladoi')
 blob = bucket.blob('file')
 read_output = blob.download_as_string()
 data = json.loads(read_output)

 data_norm = json_normalize(data, max_level=5)
 df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])
 i = 0

 for col in b.columns:
     a,c,d,e = col.split('.')
     df.loc[i]  = [a,c,d,e,b[col][0]]
     i = i + 1

 print(df)
```

Comment: I work on Google Data Lab and there is some issue with 
`from google.cloud import storage`

Comment: tried it. 
`AttributeError: module 'google.datalab.storage' has no attribute 'Client'`

Comment: they deal with storage differently: mybucket = storage.Bucket('BUCKET_NAME'),  blob = mybucket.object('file') look on internet

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, but it's work. Also you should modify flatten function that is only picked from this [awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6027558/7348030)

```py
test = { 
   "country1":{ 
      "AdUnit1":{ 
         "floor_price1":{ 
            "feature1":1111,
            "feature2":1112
         },
         "floor_price2":{ 
            "feature1":1121
         }
      },
      "AdUnit2":{ 
         "floor_price1":{ 
            "feature1":1211
         },
         "floor_price2":{ 
            "feature1":1221
         }
      }
   },
   "country2":{ 
      "AdUnit1":{ 
         "floor_price1":{ 
            "feature1":2111,
            "feature2":2112
         }
      }
   }
}

from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
import collections

def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)

results = defaultdict(list)   
colnames = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6"]
for key, value in flatten(test).items():
    elements = key.split("_")
    elements.append(value)
    for colname, element in zip(colnames, elements):
        results[colname].append(element)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(df)
```